# Como reutilizar meu .htaccess

Tags: apache, htaccess

Tenho o seguinte arquivo

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Consigo acessar a pagina sem a extensão. Gostaria de saber como faço para passar a seguinte url

> www.exemplo.com/noticias/id

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Seguindo o exemplo essa regra procuraria o seguinte arquivo:

noticias/id.php

Você pode utilizar uma ferramenta para gerenciar as rotas.

Answer (score 0):

Na última linha:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Altera para

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?param=$2&id=$3
```

Só alterar o ?param=$2 e id=$3 com as variaveis do seu get.